# Array of Linked List, moving to the next node error;

Tags: c, arrays, linked-list, nodes

Basically I want an array of linked list, each linked list having it's own header. 
This is my code:

```
struct node{
    int location;
    struct node *next;
    struct node *previous;
};

typedef struct ListHeader{
    nodeType *first;
    nodeType *current;
    nodeType *last;
} ListHeader;

struct adjList{
    ListHeader *header;
    int size;
};

struct List{
    adjListType *list;
    int size;
};

ListType newList(int numVerts){
    ListType new = malloc(sizeof(struct List));
    new->list = calloc(numVerts, sizeof(adjListType));
    new->size = numVerts;
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i <= numVerts; i++){
        new->list[i] = newAdjList();
    }
    return new;
}

adjListType newAdjList(void){
    adjListType new = malloc(sizeof(struct adjList));
    new->header = malloc(sizeof(ListHeader));
    new->header->first = NULL;
    new->header->current = NULL;
    new->header->last = NULL;
    new->size = 0; 
    return new;
}

nodeType newNode(int location){
    nodeType new = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    new->location = location;
    return new;
}
```

and it gives me an error when I try to move to the next node in the linked list with this code
(ListType l, int location)

```
l->list[location]->header->current = l->list[location]->header->current->next;
```

This is the error I am getting:

Member reference base type 'nodeType' (aka 'struct node*') is not a structure or union

Comment: in my header file I define node as 

typedef struct node *nodeType;

Comment: @user2416553 For me, there are a lot of pointers there, that you may not need at all.

Comment: @user2416553 what Kraken suggest is very good as far as "design" is concerned. I updated my answer with your design.

Answer (score 1):

if you want array of linked list, why use pointer?

```
struct List{
    adjListType list[10];
    int size;
};
```

Ofcourse you can use Pointer too but then you need to show us how you allocating Array Memory to it using `calloc`?

---

As per updated code in question ..below are error fixed lines...

```
ListType newList(int numVerts){
    ListType new = malloc(sizeof(struct List));
    new->list = calloc(numVerts, sizeof(struct adjListType));//Here you missed struct
    new->size = numVerts;
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < numVerts; i++){ // Here <= instead of < for 10 length array is 0 to 9
        new->list[i] = newAdjList();
    }
    return new;
}
```

Also You might want to return  &new as a reference or you will end up creating un-necessary copies...

I am going to your code, and will update this answer if i found anything else.. meanwhile it will be great if you can tell us what error you get?

Also in your shown code you are setting `next` and `prev` and `current` to `NULL` but where you are changing those values... otherwise you will keep on getting `NULL POINTER EXCEPTION`

Comment: Yes I am using calloc, I have read an input to determine the size of the array. And yes I am using Calloc.

Comment: I am using pointers because they will be very useful for future functions that I am going to create.

Comment: I added the "struct" in front of adjListType and it spits out:

Invalid application of 'sizeof' to an incomplete type 'struct adjListType'

Comment: Also I am initializing the values of next, previous, first, current, and last when I insert/create a node.

Comment: if `sizeof(struct List)` is working fine.. then whats wrong in `sizeof(struct adjListType)`? check for spelling mistake

Comment: No, it gives me an " Invalid application of 'sizeof' to an incomplete type 'struct adjListType'"

Answer (score 0):

Create an array of pointer to `struct node`. That should be enough for an array of linked list.

Each element of the array, i.e. the pointer to `struct node` will act as the header of list and the list can be maintained by subsequently adding/removing element from list.